# Excel - how to display text using criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone help me with this. I don't know what the formula would be?

The following criteria should be used to display text in the Matriculated column:

- If they Admitted & paid the deposit, display “Enrolling”.
- If they did not pay their deposit but in Admitted-list “Not Enrolling”.
- For all other applicants should display “Not Admitted” in the Matriculated field.

[image]

Comment: By definition, Count() and Sumif() return numbers, not text.  Your screenshot does not have the data to create the logic required for your desired results. How would Excel determine if someone matriculated? Where does it show if they paid their deposit? Explain the expected result. As a new user, please read this carefully: edit your question to provide these details. Then post a comment to alert the followers of this question.

Comment: Also, this smacks of a homework assignment. Show what you have tried, because we won't do your homework for you and you get the credits.

Comment: Would you want it to count text syntax errors like upper or lower CAse?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2016, the [`IFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60655&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) provides the simplest way to get the data you want in the Metriculated column. This allows you to perform several tests, and return a value for the first test that is successful.

Put the following formula in cell G2 and copy to the other cells in column G:

```
=IFS(E2<>"Admit","Not Admitted",F2="Yes","Enrolling",TRUE,"Not Enrolling")
```

The formula will do the following:

1. If the Decision (column E) is **not** "Admit", it returns "Not Admitted". Otherwise...
2. If Enrollment Deposit (Column F) is "Yes", it returns "Enrolling". Otherwise...
3. It returns "Not Enrolling".

Note that `IFS` doesn't provide an Else option. There needs to be a test for each possible return value. The formula uses `TRUE` as the last test (as `TRUE` is always true).

Answer (score 0):

**On the basis of the OP's criteria, I would like to suggest the following Formula in Matriculated Column.**

```
=IF(AND(E2="Admit",F2="Yes"),"Enrolling",IF(AND(E2="Admit",F2<>"Yes"),"Not Enrolling","Not Admitted"))
```

**NB:** *To test all the criteria with the suggested Formula, I've purposely used some of the Rows only.*

[image]
*I do hope this help you.*